# How to select a face of a torus using python?

Tags: python, modeling, scripting

I have to automate the face selection process of torus.
**What is the python command to select the face ?**[image]

**How can I extend this to select a loop of faces?**

**I want python script which when run will select a face of torus**

Comment: What is the criteria to select the initial face?

Answer (score 1):

For 1 click script [image]
Add torus -- go to edit mode --- select a single face (confirm that ur in face selection) -- run

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.faces_select_linked_flat(sharpness=0.261799)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=3, offset=0)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 0.5), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

If you just want to select a face loop
Add torus -- go to edit mode --- select a single face (confirm that you're in face selection) -- run

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.faces_select_linked_flat(sharpness=0.261799)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to automate the complte process pls help!

Comment: 2 method given above as u said 1st is full automate just add a torus and select a face and run and 2nd is just to select face loop

Comment: But selecting a face is not automation.Is there a command to select the face? Pls help